# Position a sticky footer next to a fixed left column under a sticky header

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Happy New Year everyone! I need help from a more experienced html/css architect. I'm having trouble creating a CSS and Html only(No Javascript) custom layout. That includes:

> **1.** Top sticky header, fully stretched 100% width of the page
>
> **2.** Left menu that sits under the header and is fully stretched to the bottom of the page in height, and dissapears if you resize the
>   width of the page (media min-width of 845px)
>
> **3.** a sticky footer that is position next to the left menu but stretched the full remaining width of the page.

[image]

This is my layout so far: http://jsfiddle.net/fksxb09y/

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="header">STICKY HEADER</div>
    <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
  <div class="content">CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />
        <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT

  </div>
  <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">STICKY FOOTER</div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
> html, body, .wrap {   height: 100%; } .wrap { box-sizing:border-box; }
> 
> form {height:100%} .wrap {   min-height: 100%;   height: auto
> !important;   height: 100%;   margin-bottom: -60px;   /* for sticky
> footer to not go below page */   /* for sticky header to not overlap
> content */ } .push, .footer {   height: 60px; } .footer {  
> background-color: green;     height: 60px;   width: 100%;   position:
> fixed;   bottom: 0; } .content {   padding-top: 60px;  height:100% 
> !important;    background-color: yellow; } .header {  
> background-color: blue;   height: 60px;    width: 100%;   position:
> fixed;   top: 0; }
> 
> 
> #sidebar-wrapper {
>     z-index: 1000;
>     position: fixed;
>     left: 250px;
>     width: 0;
>     height: 100%;
>     margin-left: -250px;
>     overflow-y: auto;
>     background: #000;
>     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
>     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
>     -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
>     transition: all 0.5s ease; }
> 
> #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
>     width: 250px; }
> 
> #page-content-wrapper {
>     width: 100%;
>     position: absolute;
>     padding: 15px; }
> 
> #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
>     position: absolute;
>     margin-right: -250px; }
> 
> /* Sidebar Styles */
> 
> .sidebar-nav {
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 0;
>     width: 250px;
>     margin: 0;
>     padding: 0;
>     list-style: none; }
> 
> .sidebar-nav li {
>     text-indent: 20px;
>     line-height: 40px; }
> 
> .sidebar-nav li a {
>     display: block;
>     text-decoration: none;
>     color: #999999; }
> 
> .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
>     text-decoration: none;
>     color: #fff;
>     background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2); }
> 
> .sidebar-nav li a:active, .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
>     text-decoration: none; }
> 
> .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
>     height: 65px;
>     font-size: 18px;
>     line-height: 60px; }
> 
> .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
>     color: #999999; }
> 
> .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
>     color: #fff;
>     background: none; }
> 
> @media(min-width:768px) {
>     #wrapper {
>         padding-left: 250px;
>     }
> 
>     #wrapper.toggled {
>         padding-left: 0;
>     }
> 
>     #sidebar-wrapper {
>         width: 250px;
>     }
> 
>     #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
>         width: 0;
>     }
> 
>     #page-content-wrapper {
>         padding: 20px;
>         position: relative;
>     }
> 
>     #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
>         position: relative;
>         margin-right: 0;
>     } }
```

As you see I'm having problems filling up the entire height of the content section without the white space at the bottom when I stretch it.

The left column layout covers the header and footer instead of the header being placed on top and the footer to the side of the left column.

**I'm hopelessly stuck right now, and need help in figuring out this layout. Any help or tips in the right direction will be greatly appreciated. Thank You!**

**UPDATE 1:** Almost solved the problem thanks to @DaMaGeX http://jsfiddle.net/fksxb09y/9/

Now I just need to figure out:

> **1.** Why the body leaves a white space at the
>   bottom when resizing.
>
> **2.** When reisizing the height of the browser
>   window the sticky footer overlaps the header, and the min-height of
>   the content section dissapears. There should be a big enough space for the content when resizing.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** Now there's another problem that I didn't notice the bottom arrow on the left menu dissapears on resize, and the content on the bottom also dissapears. http://jsfiddle.net/fksxb09y/9/

[image]

Comment: Thanks also a happy new year !!! And very nice description of your problem

Comment: Thanks @MarioKurzweil Have a Happy New Year as well!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've looked into it and here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/fksxb09y/9/

I've done the following:

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 60px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    top: 60px; //Leave the other values in.
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
    .content, .footer {
        width: 75%;
        right: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're awesome! I updated the code according to your changes, and outlined the 2 remaining problems with the code.  Which is a spacing issue when resizing the content section

Comment: Yea, I also suggest that you set the left margin of the menu to -25% instead of -250px etc. - and I don't know what you mean by a spacing issue, but if it's the whitespace that's visible a couple of seconds then add a transition to the .content and .footer elements too.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the problem. The problem is that the sticky footer goes over the sticky header when resizing(can't we keep the header on top? and add a minn height to content?, and the content window shows a white space at the bottom when resizing.

Comment: In this case you can choose to give the body element a background-color. And for the footer z-index: -1;

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I've added the changes, and I just notices a mistake we both overlooked. When you resize the browser window there is no visible down arrow or content on the left menu. It just dissapears to the bottom of the screen. Check out my update2.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I'm unsure of how to fix this at the moment. I know it's caused by the combination of sidebar wrapper fixed position, 100% height and 60px top offset. You'll have to find a way of setting the height to fill up the remaining area. Or you can set the height of the header to 10% and the height of the sidebar to 90%.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a skeleton that should do the trick:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>So many stickies!</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* My screen resolution is 1280x1024. I'm sizing elements relative to that */
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #header {
                background-color: yellow;
                width: 100%;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0px;
                height: 50px;
            }
            #left {
                background-color: blue;
                height: auto;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 280px;
                max-height: 974px;
                overflow: auto;
            }
            #right {
                height: 974px;
                width: 1000px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50px;
                left: 280px;
            }
            #bodyContent {
                width: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
                height: auto;
                max-height: 874px;
                position: relative;
                top: 0px;
            }
            #footer {
                width: 100%;
                background-color: red;
                height: 100px;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            Your header.
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="left">
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <div id="bodyContent">
                    The body
                </div>
                <div id="footer">
                    The footer
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I seem to have a similar problem with your code than the above fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fksxb09y/9/ when resizing I get a white space in the content section and the footer goes over the header

Comment: That's strange... I experienced nothing like that. I was using the latest version of chrome to test the code

Comment: You could try using em measurements instead of px measurements with my code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b8mL847g/ I've tried it on the latest Chrome, Firefox, and IE with the same issue. The left menu's down arrow and content dissapears from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: It doesn't disappear. What's happening is the height of the box isn't resized when your browser's is and so some of its area goes outside the browser's viewport

Comment: Yes correct, replacing the px with em isnt making a different. The bottom area goes outside of the viewport  whenever I resize

Comment: then I guess we're just gonna have to experiment a little more

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand the question exacly but I have some suggestions. If nav and footer will be fixed you should give some padding the content div like

```
padding: 70px 10px;
```

70px for top and bottom, 10px for left and right.

And if you want to set the content div's height 100% of the browser window you should set the css

```
height:100vh;
```

vh is the 100% of device screen height and vw is the width.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is the correct code with much help from @damagex I figured out the layout, and solved the problem that was causing the spacing issue with the bottom scrollbar.

> Following the above latest code: In the CSS section I basically removed the **height**
>   and **margin-bottom:60px** parameter from the div:
>   **#sidebar-wrapper** and added **bottom:0px.**  to stretch the sidebar to the bottom. (**Note:** This makes the left menu resize without pushing the bottom scrollbar or content out of the viewport no matter the height)

**Here's the correct fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/fksxb09y/11/

And now for the entire code, for those users who may have a similar problem  to mine. Happy New Year 2016 Everyone! :)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="header">STICKY HEADER</div>
    <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
  <div class="content">CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />
        <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT
    <br />CONTENT

  </div>
  <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">STICKY FOOTER</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body, .wrap {
  height: 100%; 
}
body {
background-color: yellow;
}

.wrap { box-sizing:border-box; }

form {height:100%}
.wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -60px;
  /* for sticky footer to not go below page */
  /* for sticky header to not overlap content */
}
.push, .footer {
  height: 60px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: green;  
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 60px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.header {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 60px; 
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}


#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    top: 60px;
    width: 0;
    bottom:0px;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (min-height:405px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 25%;
    }

    .content, .footer {
        width: 75%;
        right: 0;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }


    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```